# Microphone is suspended

Tags: microphone

I wanted to talk with friends and realised that my microphone is not working. Terminal says it is "suspended" .
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLn42.png)[another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpc2p.png)
[now it is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSj3n.png)
I have tried Rebooting, sudo apt upgrade, alsa force-reload and many other things.

Comment: "*Terminal says it is "suspended"*": How did you arrive at this?  Edit your question and include more context and details

Comment: added that 2 images

Comment: Now it is running but mic is still not working